# Clear cached SMB session (password)

Tags: windows, smb

I have accessed `\\myshare` and now I want to clear the cached password, so I am asked again for a password when connecting. I can't do it as I have medium integrity level:

```
net session \\myshare /delete
System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.
```

However, if I run the command line as administrator, no session is found under this level:

```
net session \\myshare /delete
A session does not exist with that computer name.
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried the Credential Manager?

Comment: Are you running the delete commands NOT elevated as administrator from command prompt?

Comment: I don't think my SMB credential is stored in a way the Credential Manager finds them. I have to input the password each time I connect, but then it is normally cached by Windows during the session

Comment: Ofc, delete without administrator - that's why I get the System error 5. When it's elevated, no session is found

Comment: @user1156544 Does that confirm that running it not elevated indeed resolved the problem?

Comment: No, running it as not elevated gives `Access is denied`. Running it as elevated, has no problem with access, but the sessions do not exist. It's like they were created for a specific integrity level of the user